# Calculate how many years need your money to duplicate in the bank inputing the interest

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def inversio(interes_fix_anual):
    interes_fix_anual=float(interes_fix_anual)
    money = input('Write here your credit ')
    interes = interes_fix_anual/100
    years = 0
    while money <= money*2:
        inversion = money+money*interes
        years = years+1
    return years
```

I checked the program for a long time and I didn't found the mistake, can anyone help me?

Comment: Please detail what "mistake" you have? What are the input numbers and what is the expected output?

Comment: My input number is (inversio(4)) And it's supposed to output how many years you need for get the double of your money in the bank. The program just ask me the input and then it didn't gives me the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several problems. Take out the `print` statement after you have seen the results.

```
>>> def inversio(interes_fix_anual):
...     interes_fix_anual=float(interes_fix_anual)
...     money = input('Write here your credit ')
...     interes = interes_fix_anual / 100.0
...     years = 0
...     inversion = money
...     while inversion <= (money * 2):
...         inversion = inversion + (inversion * interes)
...         years = years+1
...         print 'money=' + str(money) + ' inversion=' + str(inversion) + ' years=' + str(years)
...     return years
...
>>> inversio(4)
Write here your credit 100
money=100 inversion=104.0 years=1
money=100 inversion=108.16 years=2
money=100 inversion=112.4864 years=3
money=100 inversion=116.985856 years=4
money=100 inversion=121.66529024 years=5
money=100 inversion=126.53190185 years=6
money=100 inversion=131.593177924 years=7
money=100 inversion=136.856905041 years=8
money=100 inversion=142.331181242 years=9
money=100 inversion=148.024428492 years=10
money=100 inversion=153.945405632 years=11
money=100 inversion=160.103221857 years=12
money=100 inversion=166.507350731 years=13
money=100 inversion=173.16764476 years=14
money=100 inversion=180.094350551 years=15
money=100 inversion=187.298124573 years=16
money=100 inversion=194.790049556 years=17
money=100 inversion=202.581651538 years=18
18
```